# Return max by two columns within dataset?

Tags: max, hana, hana-sql-script

The problem I am facing is I am trying to query SAP HANA to bring back a list of unique codes that refer to one instance of a change being made to a database. For a bit of background to the below image, each change has a relevant **Site ID** and **Product No.** that I am using together as variables, in order to find out the **TS Number** for the most recent date.

[image]

However, when I use the `SELECT MAX(DATAB)` function, it forces me to use a`GROUP BY` clause. But, because I cannot omit the **TS Number** from the `GROUP BY` clause, it returns all three.

Is there a way to get the max date, for any given combination of **Product No.** and **Site ID**, and only return the **TS Number** for that date? In this example, it would be fine to use `TOP 1` but this is just a scaled-down example from a query that will look at many combinations of **Product No.** and **Site ID** (with the desired outcome being a list of all of the **TS Number**s that relate to the most recent change for that product/store combination, that I will use for a join to another query).

Any help would be appreciated. If full table design etc. is required so that people can attempt to replicate the problem I will happily provide this but am hoping there's a simple solution I have not thought of...

Many thanks

Comment: Please show the query you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in any other SQL-DB that supports window functions, you can use row_number() or rank() function to get the desired result. Which one to use depends on how you want to handle tie values.

If you just want exactly one TS-Number in case there are more than one TS-Number for the same MAXDATE, use the following SQL:

```
select dat, ts_nr, pr_nr, site
  from
  (select *, row_number() over ( partition by pr_nr, site order by dat desc ) rownum 
      from mytab
  )
    where rownum = 1;
```

Be aware, that the result is non-deterministic. However, you can (should in most cases!) make it deterministic by adding ts_nr to the order by in the window order by clause. Then you get either the highest or lowest TS-Number for the same MAXDATE, depending on the sort order.

If you want all TS-Numbers in case there are several TS-Numbers for the same MAXDATE, use rank() instead of row_number(), like this:

```
select dat, ts_nr, pr_nr, site
  from
  (select *, rank() over ( partition by pr_nr, site order by dat desc ) ranknum
      from mytab
  )
    where ranknum = 1;
```